# How do I plot a line for the the high and low of the Asia session up to the start of the next session, if the current session is consolidating?

Tags: pine-script

I have been looking at various online references and tutorials in order to research this. I am new to Pine but from a Python background.

What I am trying to do is plot the high and low of the Asia session on TradingView so that it spans across to the start of the next session, if consolidating during the Asia timeframe.

I have managed to achieve this, nearly (see below).

[image: Image of a trading graph]

See code below:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AlfieJ04

//@version=4
study("Asia Consolidation and Breakout Indicator", shorttitle="ACBI", overlay=true)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Inputs

timeframe               = input(title="Session", type=input.session, defval="1700-0300:12345") // Asia session Monday to Friday
bgColor                 = input(title="Disable background?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
lookbackLeft            = input(title="Lookback Left", type=input.integer, defval=20)
lookbackRight           = input(title="Lookback Right", type=input.integer, defval=5)
percentage              = input(title="Consolidation Threshold", type=input.float, defval=2.0)
asia                    = input(title="Show Asia Session?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
extendType              = input(false, title="Extend Lines?") ? extend.right : extend.none
showPrice               = input(true, title="Show Prices?")

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Variables

asiaColor               = color.blue
threshold               = 1 - (percentage / 100)
maxClose                = highest(high, lookbackLeft)[1]
minClose                = lowest(low, lookbackLeft)[1]
float asiaMaxHigh       = na
float asiaMinLow        = na
bool consolidating      = na
bool breakout           = na
bool breakdown          = na
float asiaHigh          = na
float asiaLow           = na

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Determine if we are in a session

asiaSession             = not na(time(timeframe.period, timeframe))
newSession              = asiaSession and not asiaSession[1]

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define consolidating and breakout/breakdown

if asiaSession
    consolidating := minClose > (maxClose * threshold) ? true : false
    
if not asiaSession
    breakout := not consolidating and close > maxClose ? true : false
    breakdown := not consolidating and close < minClose ? true : false

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Plot Asia Session to screen

bgcolor(asiaSession and asia and not bgColor ? asiaColor : na, transp=90)
barcolor(consolidating ? color.purple : na)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asiaMaxHigh             := asiaSession ? maxClose[1] : asiaMaxHigh[1]
asiaMinLow              := asiaSession ? minClose[1] : asiaMinLow[1]


plot(asiaMaxHigh, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, title='Asia High')
plot(asiaMinLow, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, title='Asia Low')
```

Comment: A couple of questions.
1. In what timezone is this expressed? `defval="1700-0300:12345") // Asia session Monday to Friday` 
2. Where can we find the Asia session trading hours on the internet? 
3. Do you want the `high/low` of the Asian session only to be displayed when that Asian session is not active? 4. Do you need this only for `EUR/USD` (trades in UTC-5), or also for tickers that trade in other timezones?

Comment: I found this [The forex 3-session system](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/forex/08/3-market-system.asp) which says either midnight to 6 a.m. GMT or between 11 p.m. and 8 a.m. GMT

Comment: Hi Bjorn,

Thanks for the reply.

The hours should be around 2200 to 0800 GMT, however when I used that to express the Asian session, the session plots were in the wrong place.

I would like the Asian high and low plotted from the previous day, up to the current session, whether we are in that session or not.

And yes, I would like this to be available for all tickers.

Thanks,

Alfie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should plot what you're looking for.
It tracks the `high` and `low` during the Asia session, and only starts plotting when the Asia session is not active anymore.

```
//@version=4
study("Asia Session", overlay=true)

var hourSessionStart = input(22, "Asia session start hour (GMT)", minval=0, maxval=23)
var hourSessionStop  = input(08, "Asia session end hour (GMT)", minval=0, maxval=23)

var float hi              = na
var float lo              = na
var float plotHi          = na
var float plotLo          = na

var int   currentHourGMT  = na
var bool  inSession       = na
var bool  enteringSession = na
var bool  exitingSession  = na

currentHourGMT  := hour(time, "GMT")
inSession       := (currentHourGMT >= hourSessionStart or currentHourGMT < hourSessionStop)
enteringSession := inSession and not inSession[1]
exitingSession  := not inSession and inSession[1]

if enteringSession
    plotLo := na
    plotHi := na

if inSession
    lo := min(low,  nz(lo, 1.0e23))
    hi := max(high, nz(hi))

if exitingSession
    plotLo := lo
    plotHi := hi
    lo     := na
    hi     := na

bgcolor(inSession ? color.blue : na)

plot(plotLo, "Asia session Low",  color.red,   style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(plotHi, "Asia session High", color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Hey Bjorn,

Thanks for this! Works exactly as described!

Alfie

Comment: I liked this, very clean code and I tried to modify it. I tried to draw a box around the asia session while it was forming, and also print the current height of the box in pips. The box+pips should change during the session and of course stay after the session is over. I didn't manage any of that. However, I did manage to print the range in pips at the end of the asia session, and draw the hi+lo during the session - better than nothing. Pip text currently only works for some pairs like gbpusd (difference in price / 0.0001). Any hints for the box+pips? Thx!